# Flutter onPressed async function not waiting for await function from cubit/repository

Tags: android, flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I have a signup button which sends an http request to my API. I want to navigate off of the signup page after the request is completed. Using bloc pattern, I add an event to the bloc to navigate to the login page but the signup page isn't waiting for http request to be completed before adding event to bloc.

Signup Button code :-

```
class _SignUpButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.status != current.status,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return state.status.isSubmissionInProgress
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : IconButton(
                key: const Key('loginForm_continue_raisedButton'),
                onPressed: state.status.isValidated
                    ? () async {
                      await context.bloc<SignUpCubit>().signUpFormSubmitted();
                      context.bloc<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationUserChanged(User.empty));
                    }
                    : () => print('invalid'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 40,
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Signup cubit :-

```
part 'signup_state.dart';

class SignUpCubit extends Cubit<SignUpState> {
  SignUpCubit(this._authenticationRepository)
      : assert(_authenticationRepository != null),
        super(const SignUpState());

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;

  //irrelevant code omitted

  Future<void> signUpFormSubmitted() async {
    if (!state.status.isValidated) return;
    emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionInProgress));
    try {
      await _authenticationRepository.signUp(
          name: state.name,
          password: state.password.value,
          mobile: state.mobile.value,
          village: state.village,
          email: state.email.value,
          pincode: state.pincode);
      emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess));
    } on Exception {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure));
    }
  }
}
```

Authentication repository :-

```
/// Thrown if during the sign up process if a failure occurs.
class SignUpFailure implements Exception {}

class AuthenticationRepository {
  /// {@macro authentication_repository}
  AuthenticationRepository({
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth,
    GoogleSignIn googleSignIn,
  })  : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance,
        _googleSignIn = googleSignIn ?? GoogleSignIn.standard();

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;

  /// Stream of [User] which will emit the current user when
  /// the authentication state changes.
  ///
  /// Emits [User.empty] if the user is not authenticated.
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((firebaseUser) {
      return firebaseUser == null ? User.empty : firebaseUser.toUser;
    });
  }

  //irrelevant code omitted

  Future<void> signUp(
      {@required String name,
      @required String password,
      @required String mobile,
      @required String village,
      @required String pincode,
      @required String email}) async {
    assert(
        name != null && mobile != null && village != null && pincode != null);
    try {
      if (email != '' && password != '') {
        await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
      }
      final params = {
        'name': name,
        'phone': mobile,
        'village': village + '_' + pincode,
        'api': 't',
        'login': 'NA'
      };
      Response res = await Dio().get(
          "https://us-central1-greensat-9087a.cloudfunctions.net/addUser",
          queryParameters: params);
      print(res.data);
    } on Exception {
      throw SignUpFailure();
    }
  }  

}
```

Authentication bloc :-

```
class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  AuthenticationBloc({
    @required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
  })  : assert(authenticationRepository != null),
        _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(const AuthenticationState.unknown()) {
    _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
      (user) => add(AuthenticationUserChanged(user)),
    );
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  StreamSubscription<User> _userSubscription;

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AuthenticationUserChanged) {
      yield _mapAuthenticationUserChangedToState(event);
    } else if (event is AuthenticationLogoutRequested) {
      unawaited(_authenticationRepository.logOut());
    } else if (event is AuthenticationOTPRequested) {
      yield _mapAuthenticationUserOTPRequested(event);
    } else if (event is AuthenticationSignupStarted) {
      yield _mapAuthenticationUserSignupStarted(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  AuthenticationState _mapAuthenticationUserChangedToState(
    AuthenticationUserChanged event,
  ) {
    print('user changed state');
    print(event.user);
    return event.user != User.empty
        ? AuthenticationState.authenticated(event.user)
        : const AuthenticationState.unauthenticated();
  }

  AuthenticationState _mapAuthenticationUserOTPRequested(
    AuthenticationOTPRequested event,
  ) {
    return const AuthenticationState.unauthenticatedOTP();
  }

  AuthenticationState _mapAuthenticationUserSignupStarted(
    AuthenticationSignupStarted event,
  ) {
    return const AuthenticationState.signupStarted();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use async in a cubit emitter function

INCORRECT: ⛔️

```
void increment() async => emit(state+1)
```

CORRECT: ✅

```
void increment() => emit(state+1)
```